# hideshow within a table

Tags: javascript, vbscript, asp-classic

I'm trying to click-to-show some text within a table with the following code:

```
<%      
  if isarray(myArray) <> FALSE then
  For Counter = 0 to RowNumber
%>
<tr>
 <td>col1</td>
 <td>col2</td>
 <td><a href="javascript:hideshow(document.getElementById('adiv'))"><img src="/bullet.png"/></a>
 <div id="adiv" style="display:none">Hello</div></td>
</tr>
```

I want the revealed text to appear within the same `<td>`, on the same row that was clicked but it always appears on the first row of the table, regardless of which row is clicked.

Could someone point out what I'm missing here?

-EDIT-
Removed orphan div and closed `<a>` tag wrt Rick Hitchcock's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `a` tag isn't closed, and you have an orphan `</div>` tag:

```
... <img src="/bullet.png"/><a></div> ...
```

Change to this:

```
... <img src="/bullet.png"/></a> ...
```

Also:  `id`s must be unique, but you have the same "adiv" `id` on each row of your table.  You could remove the `id` and do this instead:

```
<td>
  <a onclick="hideshow(this.parentNode.querySelector('div'))">
    <img src="/bullet.png"/>
  </a>
  <div style="display:none">Hello</div>
</td>
```

Comment: D'Oh, thanks but it still appears on the first row. I'll edit the OP.

Comment: That's probably because you have more than one `div` with id "adiv."  `getElementById` returns the first one in that instance.  See my update.

Comment: Ah, that's what it was. Thank you very much Rick. I'll accept your answer as soon as SO allows.